# Thumbnail remove width & height function

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, images

I wish that when the browser was resized to below 980px, my images were width 100%. The container of the images already have 100%, the problem is that I'm using wordpress size  code for thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support ('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size ('portfolio1', 600, 344, true);
```

So I thought to use this code to remove the image sizes:

```
jQuery (document). ready (function ($) {
     $ ('img'). RemoveProp ('width'). RemoveProp ('height');
});
```

The problem is that I do not know how it would look for smaller sizes that 980px browser.
I do not know if this is the best way.
I Would like some help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This snippes should remove the `height` and `width` attributes of the images:
https://gist.github.com/stuntbox/4557917

Maby you would extend the code to only strip out the attributes on images larger than 980px?.